# Glassfish redirect_n recursion

Tags: glassfish, virtualhost

I've a problem with the Glassfish V3 virtual hosts and redirecting capabilities.

1. I have a domain : **example.com** ;-)
2. I host my app on : **www.example.com** [OK with default application and dedicated virtual server]
3. I'd like example.com redirect to www.example.com with a "301 HTTP status code" to prevent duplicate content

As mentioned in glassfish documentation, I used the 'redirect_n' virtual hosts property with :

```
value="from=/ url-prefix=www.example.com"
```

...on a new dedicated virtual host but it was resulting in a recursive call by the redirector and a REQUEST URI TOO LARGE Grizzly error !

Is there anyone that has tried this, getting a better result ?

Thanks for your help,
Seth.